# Concate string path in psql command line

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have to merge path directory and **actual** time in psql command line.
This absolute path works well:

```
\copy (select row_to_json(row(column1,column5)) from testdatabase.test) TO 'C:\Users\path\file.json';
```

But when I want merge two string like this:

```
\copy (select row_to_json(row(column1,column5)) from testdatabase.test) TO 'C:\Users\path\' || to_char(now(), 'YYYY_MM_DD');
```

I get Permission denied. This is permission issue i think because first request works well on same path. I tried also CONCATE statement but it fails.

Comment: The file name must be a constant.

Comment: So is there any way to declare const in psql command line **before** and use it in my request?

Comment: I don't think this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If using `COPY` directly is an option, you could dynamically build the command, including your custom path logic and `EXECUTE` it. For example in an anonymous `DO` block:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT row_to_json(...) ...) TO ''C:\...\' || to_char(now(), 'YYYY_MM_DD') || '.json''';
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to be a good solution, but I get a Permission denied to path and suggestions to use '\copy' when I run it in shell psql. But even with the use of '\copy' , it gets a syntax error near to '\' sign...